# SQL get row count from every table tenantwise

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I am working on a multitenant application. Most of the tables contain a column tenant_id. I want the number of rows in all tables for a particular tenant_id.

Example,
Tables:-

```
create table Employee(id integer, name varchar(100), tenantid integer);
insert into Employee(id, name, tenantid) values(1, "Stephan", 64);
insert into Employee(id, name, tenantid) values(2, "Alan", 64);
insert into Employee(id, name, tenantid) values(3, "Charles", 46);

create table Student(id integer, name varchar(100), standard integer, tenantid integer);
insert into Student(id, name, standard, tenantid) values(1, "James", 2, 64);
insert into Student(id, name, standard, tenantid) values(2, "Rony", 4, 64);
insert into Student(id, name, standard, tenantid) values(3, "Steve",6, 64);

create table Teacher(id integer, name varchar(100), subject varchar(100), tenantid integer);
insert into Teacher(id, name, subject, tenantid) values(1, "Alvin", "Science", 46);
insert into Teacher(id, name, subject, tenantid) values(2, "Neil", "Geography", 64);
insert into Teacher(id, name, subject, tenantid) values(3, "Amy", "Mathematics", 46);`
```

Sample result to get number of rows in every table having tenantid = 64

| TableName | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Employee | 2 |
| Student | 3 |
| Teacher | 1 |

How do I loop through all the tables and query `where tenantid = <tenantid>`

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Dynamic Query. Form the query dynamically for each table and use `string_agg()` to concatenate it and execute the query using `sp_executesql`

```
declare @tables varchar(max),
        @tenantid int,
        @sql nvarchar(max)

select @tables = 'Employee,Student,Teacher',
       @tenantid = 64;

select @sql = string_agg('select [TableName] = ''' + value + ''', [Count] = count(*) from ' + quotename(value) + ' where tenantid = @tenantid', ' union all' + char(13) )
from   string_split(@tables, ',')

print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@tenantid int', @tenantid
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/T2BqPKch)

Comment: Thanks, In reality, my tables are inside schemas. When providing tables as below
select @tables = 'schemaName.Employee,schemaName.Students',
I am getting the error -  "Invalid object name schemaName.Employee"

Comment: change `quotename(value)` to `value`

Comment: Or change to `quotename(parsename(value, 2)) + '.' + quotename(parsename(value, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION ALL:

```sql
SELECT 'Employee' AS "TableName", COUNT(*) AS "Count" FROM Employee WHERE tenantid = 64
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Student' AS "TableName", COUNT(*) AS "Count" FROM Student WHERE tenantid = 64
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Teacher' AS "TableName", COUNT(*) AS "Count" FROM Teacher WHERE tenantid = 64
```

View example (I'm not sure about efficiency):

```sql
CREATE VIEW some_counters_view AS
SELECT 'Employee' AS "TableName", tenantid FROM Employee
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Student' AS "TableName", tenantid FROM Student
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Teacher' AS "TableName", tenantid FROM Teacher
;

SELECT "TableName", COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM some_counters_view 
WHERE tenantid = 64
GROUP BY "TableName"
```

Comment: I have 100s of table. I want to pass tableNames list and tenantId as parameters.

Comment: @UmeshMalhotra you could write a function that will do it for you, or just create a VIEW

Comment: @UmeshMalhotra see Squirrel's answer for dynamic SQL function or see my updated answer for VIEW (but I'm not sure about VIEW's efficiency, you have to test it's performance)